# Changing the Picker Appearence in sencha touch

Tags: sencha-touch, picker

I am facing some problem in changing the picker view in sencha touch. 
I want to call the picker in the right hand side of my view rather than coming from the bottom in a streched manner without making any changes to the sencha touch 2.1.0 libraries.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can set that using **Enter** or **Exit** config (or) `setEnter()` method on your Picker. Something like this:

```
                        xtype: 'picker',
                        enter: 'left',
                        exit: 'right',
                        slots: [
                            {
                                xtype: 'pickerslot',
                                name: 'MyPickerSlot',
                                title: 'MyPickerSlot',
                                data: [
                                    {
                                        text: 'One',
                                        value: 1
                                    },
                                    {
                                        text: 'Two',
                                        value: 2
                                    },
                                    {
                                        text: 'Three',
                                        value: 3
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
```